# How to run pg_xlogdump or pg_waldump in Google CloudSQL? Or use Query Insights to get similar results?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

Does anyone know how to look up the transaction that’s associated with an LSN on a CloudSQL Postgres instance?

For example, let’s say I’m trying to find the transaction associated with LSN `842/E62E3F01`. On a normal server, I can ssh into the instance, and run `pg_waldump --start=842/E62E3F01` (or `pg_xlogdump` on Postgres < 10). But it doesn’t seem possible to ssh into a CloudSQL server. If so, how can I find the query/transaction associated with this LSN on CloudSQL?

I'm open to using [Query Insights](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/query-insights-overview) as well. Specifically, I'm having an issue where I'm trying to monitor transactions larger than 1GB. If there's a way to do this in Query Insights, that would be helpful. I can get the LSN's of these transactions, but not sure how to map them back to the actual transactions themselves.

Comment: How would you map them back using pg_waldump?  Query texts aren't present there.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure yet, but since `pg_waldump` returns a transaction id, I figured I can use that to extract more information about the query texts. I'm also exploring using `pg_logical_slot_peek_changes` to get information about the transaction associated with an LSN - I'll update this post if I found out anything useful...